# How do I express to flow that a function must polymorphically return the same type as the first parameter?

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype

I have been reading about generics and want to understand how generics work within flow.

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-function-types-with-generics

I am especially interested in the idea of using flow to check function signatures for functional programming.

However I cannot understand why the following does not work:

When I try

```
/* @flow */

const identity = (c) => c;

(identity: <T>(T) => T); // force flow to typecheck
```

Then Flow returns an error:

```
3: const identity = (c) => c;
                           ^ T. This type is incompatible with
5: (identity: <T>(T) => T);
    ^ some incompatible instantiation of `T`
```

I would have thought that because c is always c and has not been mutated it's type must match the pattern?

**Q: How do I express to flow that the function must return the same type as the first parameter?**

---

Supplimentary Example

Even when I try using a type alias it doesn't seem to work.

```
/* @flow */
type ReturnsSameTypeAsFirstParam = <T>(T) => T;

const identity:ReturnsSameTypeAsFirstParam = (c) => c;
```

I then get:

```
4: const identity:ReturnsSameTypeAsFirstParam = (c) => c;
                                                       ^ T. This type is incompatible with
4: const identity:ReturnsSameTypeAsFirstParam = (c) => c;
                                                ^ some incompatible instantiation of `T`
```

---

## EDIT: Attempt at clarification

I am mainly keen to provide a type for functions as arguments and understand how to use them polymorphically.

Perhaps this is a clearer example of the kind of thing I am trying to type:

```
/* @flow */

type Transformer = <T>(T)=>T;

function transformAGivenThing(transform:Transformer, thing:*) {
  return transform(thing);
}

function transformAString(str:string):string {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}

transformAGivenThing(transformAString, 'thing');
```

This causes these errors when I run flow:

```
3: type Transformer = <T>(T)=>T;
                       ^ T. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
9: function transformAString(str:string):string {
                             ^ string
9: function transformAString(str:string):string {
                                         ^ string. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
13: transformAGivenThing(transformAString, 'thing');
                     ^ some incompatible instantiation of `T`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I ended up submitting an issue to flow asking for the way to do this. Their answer:

```
/* @flow */

type Transformer<T> = (T)=>T;

function transformAGivenThing(transform:Transformer<*>, thing:*) {
  return transform(thing);
}

function uppercaseAString(str:string):string {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(transformAGivenThing(uppercaseAString, 'thing'));
```

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4429

What is happening is that you need to configure the `Transformer` generic type with a Type but in this case because it needs to be polymorphic the configuration should be a `*`

Comment: When calling `let s = transformAGivenThing(uppercaseAString, 'thing');`, the returned type will be `any`. If you check my updated answer, the return type is corresponding to the returned type of the given `transformer`. Proper intellisense will pick that up.

Comment: There is a difference between `*` and `any`. `*` means defer type checking downstream whilst `any` means do not type check. Because `*` defers type checking until later, the types in the generic resolve, in the example above, at the point where flow checks the `uppercaseAString` function.

Answer (score 0):

Edited regarding the addition to your post.

```
/* @flow */

const isStr = (str: string) => !!str;
const isNmbr = (nmbr: number) => !!nmbr;

function transformAny<T>(transformer: (T) => T, thing: T): T {
  return transformer(thing);
}

function transformString(thing: string): string {
  return !!thing ? thing.toUpperCase() : thing;
}

function transformNumber(thing: number): number {
  return !!thing ? thing * 10 : thing;
}

let s = transformAny(transformString, "1");

let n = transformAny(transformNumber, 5);

isStr(s);
// isStr(n);
// isNmbr(s);
isNmbr(n);
```

Uncommenting the 2 calls for typechecking will throw an error of missmatching parameter types. I dont think you can declare a custom type for one of the parameters and return the corresponding type as well. This is the first time I see this languague, but it looks very similar to TypeScript.

Comment: Hmm maybe I am not being clear enough with what I am trying to achieve here. I will attempt to update my question.

Comment: @rickard I have edited my post. Is this what you are trying to do with the generic object `transformer`?